# How do I use .map to parse response when response has inconsistent values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yelp

So I'm using the yelp API, and after I make a GET request I get back a response of businesses. In order to work with that response I'm using .map

Example:

```
mappedResults = yelpSearch.businesses.map {|l| {id: l.id, name: l.name, categories:l.categories, rating: l.rating, review_count: l.review_count, url: l.url, phone: l.phone}}
```

My problem is that sometimes l.phone is not returned for some records in the response, and I get the error:

```
undefined method `phone' for #<BurstStruct::Burst:0x007fba47c7a228>
```

My question is how do I refactor this code so that if a record doesn't have phone it will either leave it null (or worst cast empty string)

Any help is appreciated

JSON structure is as such for each business in the response

```
{
    region: {
        span: {
            latitude_delta: 0,
            longitude_delta: 0
        },
        center: {
            latitude: 38.054117,
            longitude: -84.439002
        }
    },
    total: 23,
    businesses: [
        {
            is_claimed: false,
            rating: 5,
            mobile_url: "http://m.yelp.com/biz/vineyard-community-church-lexington",
            rating_img_url: "http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/f1def11e4e79/ico/stars/v1/stars_5.png",
            review_count: 2,
            name: "Vineyard Community Church",
            snippet_image_url: "http://s3-media4.ak.yelpcdn.com/photo/VoeMtbk7NRFi6diksSUtOQ/ms.jpg",
            rating_img_url_small: "http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/c7623205d5cd/ico/stars/v1/stars_small_5.png",
            url: "http://www.yelp.com/biz/vineyard-community-church-lexington",
            phone: "8592582300",
            snippet_text: "I have been a member of Vineyard Community Church since 2004. Here you will find a modern worship service with a full band, witty speakers who teach...",
            image_url: "http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/D71eikniuaHjdOC8DB6ziA/ms.jpg",
            categories: [
                [
                    "Churches",
                    "churches"
                ]
            ],
            display_phone: "+1-859-258-2300",
            rating_img_url_large: "http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/22affc4e6c38/ico/stars/v1/stars_large_5.png",
            id: "vineyard-community-church-lexington",
            is_closed: false,
            location: {
                city: "Lexington",
                display_address: [
                    "1881 Eastland Pwky",
                    "Lexington, KY 40505"
                ],
                geo_accuracy: 8,
                postal_code: "40505",
                country_code: "US",
                address: [
                    "1881 Eastland Pwky"
                ],
                coordinate: {
                    latitude: 38.054117,
                    longitude: -84.439002
                },
                state_code: "KY"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Rails 4.0 or newer, the [#presence](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) method is really helpful for this. You would use it like this:

```
mappedResults = yelpSearch.businesses.map {|l| {id: l.id.presence, #... etc
```

or like this

```
mappedResults = yelpSearch.businesses.map {|l| {id: l.id.presence || "default id", # ...
```

**Update**

Reading your code again, #presence might not work in this case, since the method isn't defined. Here's a longer (uglier) snippet that should work:

```
mappedResults = yelpSearch.businesses.map do |l|
  id: l.respond_to(:id) ? l.id : "default id",
  # ... other properties
end
```

***Update from OP***

This worked - thank you!  Note I had to tweak syntax a bit to respond_to?('method_name')

```
  mappedResults = yelpSearch.businesses.map {|l|
    {
      name: l.respond_to?("name") ? l.name : "nameless",
    rating: l.respond_to?("rating") ? l.rating : "unrated",
    # ... other properties
    }}
```